# how to change the border of a cupertinotextfield when is focused in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to develop a form using flutter and I need to change the border of my **cupertinotextfield** when the user focused on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code you want to change, including any attempts you've made to solve your problem yourself. This helps the community to give you a more useful and relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `onFocusChange` of `FocusScope` to check focus and change `BoxDecoration` to what you need 
code snippet

```
FocusScope(
 child: Focus(
    onFocusChange: (focus) {
      if (focus) {
        setState(() {
          boxSetting = boxHasFocus;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          boxSetting = defaultBoxSetting;
        });
      }
    },
    child: CupertinoTextField(
        decoration: boxSetting, controller: _textController)))
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _textController;
  BoxDecoration boxSetting;
  BoxDecoration defaultBoxSetting = CupertinoTextField().decoration;

  BoxDecoration boxHasFocus = BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFFFFF00), width: 0.5),
    color: Color(0xFF9E9E9E),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular((20.0)),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    boxSetting = defaultBoxSetting;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FocusScope(
                child: Focus(
                    onFocusChange: (focus) {
                      if (focus) {
                        setState(() {
                          boxSetting = boxHasFocus;
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          boxSetting = defaultBoxSetting;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: CupertinoTextField(
                        decoration: boxSetting, controller: _textController))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```